# Could not create Vfs.Dir from url

Tags: jhipster

I created a microservice with data source mongodb and tried run it on my local. My mongodb is running on docker. I can access mongodb from my local. I got below error. Any suggestion?

```
2016-09-04 20:56:50.029  WARN 46100 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : could not create Vfs.Dir from url. ignoring the exception and continuing
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create Vfs.Dir from url, no matching UrlType was found [file:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DAudio.jnilib]
either use fromURL(final URL url, final List<UrlType> urlTypes) or use the static setDefaultURLTypes(final List<UrlType> urlTypes) or addDefaultURLTypes(UrlType urlType) with your specialized UrlType.
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:108)
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:90)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:236)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:203)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:128)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:169)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:142)
    at com.github.mongobee.utils.ChangeService.fetchChangeLogs(ChangeService.java:43)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.execute(Mongobee.java:142)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.afterPropertiesSet(Mongobee.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at com.xx.cloud.demo.ResourceApp.main(ResourceApp.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Cross posting here after having opened a github issue  https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4071 is not such a great idea, now you have to make sure you post same level of details to both. Also it would help if you shared your project on github.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I put my test project on google drive at this link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxjI_hvNCC9cUHhnb0tObW56Smc
I'm using Jhipster 3.6.1, and chose mongodb as my database. please take a look when you are free. thanks.

Comment: I just tried another scenario that even I didn't use uaa. it was the same error. but I could create entity successfully.

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK for your docker? If you are then check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282104/docker-spring-boot-error-could-not-create-vfs-dir-from-url/42828294#42828294


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282104/docker-spring-boot-error-could-not-create-vfs-dir-from-url/42828294#42828294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be late but I got the same issue and solved it by
checking package scan change logs declared in class DatabaseConfiguration

```
// package to scan for migrations 
mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage("com.jhipster.web.config.dbmigrations");
```

Example here package is "com.jhipster.web.config.dbmigrations". Go to that package and create a class like this:

```
package com.jhipster.web.config.dbmigrations;
import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeLog;

@ChangeLog
public class DatabaseChangelog {
}
```

Then the warning/error will gone.

Comment: The line for the first code block can be found in `com/app/config/DataBaseConfiguration.java`, then add the class file as mentioned above at the location indicated by `setChangeLogsScanPackage`